# MYSQL count() -> Return the LAST ID from Number of user using the same mail

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named "users". users(id,name,email). My table structure is as follows :
ID is primary key auto increment

I would like to return the email, count and the last_id of user that has the same email address

TABLE :

[image]

In other words, my query should return

last_id: 3 - count: 2 - email: jones@jones.com

last_id: 7 - count: 3 - email: silva@gmail.com

I know a piece of the query that returns the count, and the email that is repeated, but I can't get the last id.

SELECT email,count(email) FROM users GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(email) > 1 ORDER BY count(email) DESC

Answer (score 2):

Add `MAX()`. Also, for `COUNT(email)` you can define an alias and use it on `HAVING` & `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT email, count(email) AS cnt_email , MAX(id) AS latest_id
 FROM users GROUP BY email 
HAVING cnt_email  > 1 
ORDER BY cnt_email DESC;
```

[Here's a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/84SXd7Q3)